# How can I pull image from local repository on Digital Ocean?

Tags: digital-ocean, mesos, marathon

I tried both internal and external IP to pull the image from local repository, I am getting this error:

```
I0113 12:15:49.024701  6602 master.cpp:3760] Sending 1 offers to framework 20160113-100358-33554442-5050-2351-0001 (marathon) at scheduler-6654c9ed-c68e-4531-894f-420a093fb578@10.0.0.2:42279
I0113 12:15:49.031448  6600 master.cpp:2273] Processing ACCEPT call for offers: [ 20160113-113337-33554442-5050-6575-O37 ] on slave 20160113-100358-33554442-5050-2351-S0 at slave(1)@10.0.0.3:5051 (development-7734-cb7.c.project-sample-1180.internal) for framework 20160113-100358-33554442-5050-2351-0001 (marathon) at scheduler-6654c9ed-c68e-4531-894f-420a093fb578@10.0.0.2:42279
I0113 12:15:49.031901  6602 master.hpp:822] Adding task tomcat.619735cd-b9ef-11e5-8e8e-0242602a4b85 with resources cpus(*):0.5; mem(*):512; ports(*):[31482-31482] on slave 20160113-100358-33554442-5050-2351-S0 (development-7734-cb7.c.project-sample-1180.internal)
I0113 12:15:49.031973  6602 master.cpp:2550] Launching task tomcat.619735cd-b9ef-11e5-8e8e-0242602a4b85 of framework 20160113-100358-33554442-5050-2351-0001 (marathon) at scheduler-6654c9ed-c68e-4531-894f-420a093fb578@10.0.0.2:42279 with resources cpus(*):0.5; mem(*):512; ports(*):[31482-31482] on slave 20160113-100358-33554442-5050-2351-S0 at slave(1)@10.0.0.3:5051 (development-7734-cb7.c.project-sample-1180.internal)
I0113 12:15:49.032171  6602 hierarchical.hpp:648] Recovered cpus(*):1.4; mem(*):5947; disk(*):4974; ports(*):[31553-32000, 31000-31481, 31483-31551] (total allocatable: cpus(*):1.4; mem(*):5947; disk(*):4974; ports(*):[31553-32000, 31000-31481, 31483-31551]) on slave 20160113-100358-33554442-5050-2351-S0 from framework 20160113-100358-33554442-5050-2351-0001
I0113 12:15:49.725064  6600 master.cpp:3300] Status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 561c943e-2cae-4b9e-93e0-93fc2815bc2b) for task tomcat.619735cd-b9ef-11e5-8e8e-0242602a4b85 of framework 20160113-100358-33554442-5050-2351-0001 from slave 20160113-100358-33554442-5050-2351-S0 at slave(1)@10.0.0.3:5051 (development-7734-cb7.c.project-sample-1180.internal)
I0113 12:15:49.725160  6600 master.cpp:3341] Forwarding status update TASK_FAILED (UUID: 561c943e-2cae-4b9e-93e0-93fc2815bc2b) for task tomcat.619735cd-b9ef-11e5-8e8e-0242602a4b85 of framework 20160113-100358-33554442-5050-2351-0001
**I0113 12:15:49.725265  6600 master.cpp:4623] Updating the latest state of task tomcat.619735cd-b9ef-11e5-8e8e-0242602a4b85 of framework 20160113-100358-33554442-5050-2351-0001 to TASK_FAILED**
```

Comment: You need to provide more info. Where is the repository located? What configuration steps have you done?

Comment: This needs an [mcve] to be answerable, even though it is 2+ years old. In the meantime, I suggest it is put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't specify what configuration steps you done to allow the usage of the private registry, one can only give you the link to the overall docs regarding this topic.

Have a look at

- https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker-private-registry.html